# Serial Port Stream Line End character in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, encoding, character-encoding, character

Im streaming the data from the device and I need to find a way to catch "line end" symbol end separate lines by this symbol like any software like hyper terminal do.
But I cant catch this symbol.

For the moment the stream I receive lookslike this:

00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0     00    00
)0

But I need it to look like this in my textBox of windows Forms :

)0     00    00

)0     00    00

)0     00    00

)0     00    00

)0     00    00

)0     00    00

I've already made a code that would separate streaming string when it finds specific string in it, but to "bind" that string is tricky forme. Iknowthat shouldbean ASCII character but I can't find the way how encode it to my program and use.

P.S. Actually when I simply copypaste the craracter "" into specific texBox and then apply to variable and use in a program, it works, but it looks like it's wrong way to move becouse I cant paste it dirrectly to Visual Studio in string variable for example.

I use this event code to receive data from Serial Port:

```
    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(write_to_field)); 

        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(ex), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(ex), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(ex), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(ex), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(ex), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

And this is the method I use:

```
    public void write_to_field(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String stringToShow;
        String delimiter = textBox4.Text;
        if (textBox5.Text.Length <= Convert.ToInt16(textBox3.Text))
        {
            String DispString;
            String toFind = textBox4.Text;
            DispString = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
            int index = DispString.IndexOf(toFind);
            textBox5.AppendText(DispString);
            if (index != 0)
            {
                textBox5.AppendText(DispString.Remove(0, 1));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            stringToShow = textBox5.Text;
            textBox6.Text = stringToShow;
            textBox5.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

I think it's far from perfect, so I would very appreciate advices about it too.

After an advice I remade the code like this:

```
    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        write_to_field();

    }


    public void write_to_field() 
    {
        serialPort1.NewLine = "/r/n";
        try
        {
            textBox1.Text = serialPort1.ReadLine();
        }

        catch (TimeoutException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(ex), "Some title", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(ex), "Some title", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(ex), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(ex), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(ex), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(ex), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(ex), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

But have System.IO.IOException
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164917.aspx
means there is nothing to Read. But it sould be becouse Hyperterm can read it.

I tried to use ReadLinewhen I started  the project but it didnot work as well. I cold not find good solution anywhere. What could be wrong here?

Comment: Try reading bytes.

Comment: Can you please give more information about how you are using the SerialPort? Some code would be great. Do you already use the `NewLine` property of SerialPort? Or the `ReadLine` Method?

Comment: Ok. I've added it above in a main Question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you or providing more details of your implementation.

Based on this, I see that you are calling the `serialPort1.ReadExisting()` method. This reads all existing data stored in the serialPort buffer. You could try to specify the linebreak character and add it to the `SerialPort` as `NewLine` property. Then iterate through the `SerialPort.ReadLine` method, which reads only the data in the buffer until the next `NewLine` string is hit.

See the documentation for more details: [NewLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.ports.serialport.newline(v=vs.110).aspx), [ReadLine with example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readline(v=vs.110).aspx)

EDIT:

According to the documentation of `ReadLine` method, the `ReadLine` method should only throw `InvalidOperationException` and `TimeoutException`. I think there might be something else wrong, when an `IOException` is thrown. What does the exception message say and what is the stacktrace? Are there any `Inner Exceptions`?

Comment: So remade the project as you adviced adn as it was said in documentatio, and I got this exception: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164917.aspx

What could be wrong?

This is the code:

        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            write_to_field();
        public void write_to_field() 
        {
            try
            {
                textBox1.Text = serialPort1.ReadLine();
            }

            catch (TimeoutException ex)
            {
 .......

Comment: The code is very hard to read in the comment section. Could you edit your initial Post to show us what you changed?

Comment: added to the first post

Comment: Thank you, can you provide more Information about the exception? What is the exception text and some details? (StackTrace...)

Comment: OK. Updated the 1st post

Comment: I updated my answer, can you give more Information about the exception we are facing?